# Change the color of displayed values in pie chart

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart.js + chartjs-plugin-datalabels.

I am displaying values in the chart. I am trying to change the value colors (font color), but cannot find the way. Any suggestions?

[JSFiddle link][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/s9tu1c9y/131/
```

Answer (score 0):

In `var defaults = {}`, set the `color` attribute to whatever color you want the  value label text to be.

Currently, the value of `color` is set to `undefined`:

```
/**
 * The color used to draw the label text.
 * @member {String|Array|Function}
 * @default undefined (use Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor)
 */
color: undefined,
```

If you want all the values to be the same color, just set `color` to a single string like the following:

```
 color: 'green'
```

If you want each label to be a different color, as mentioned in the comment above the attribute, you can also set the value of `color` to an array like the following:

```
color: ['green', 'red', 'blue']
```

Working JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/s9tu1c9y/132/

Comment: Thanks for the response.... I can see that you have changed in Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor. But can we have the same thing in chart config or options as I am using other charts on the same page. I require the same as per your sample but it has to be set in the chart config or options.

Comment: @ManishPrajapati Sure, there are many ways to change to color, it is just hard to tell which code you are ok with changing since you provided a JSFiddle code dump, instead of just the minimal code recreating your problem. Another way can be changing color in the model object like shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s9tu1c9y/133/). You can dynamically pass in variables there also. If you don't want to change this either, please create a new JSFiddle with the minimum amount of code needed.

Comment: @ManishPrajapati This is also the reason you are supposed to include some code in the actual question, and not just a JSFiddle link, like mentioned in the warning message you probably got when you first created your question and when you try to edit the link to be formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the new example and sorry about that I did not mention my problem in the main question. Actually I need to change label color dynamically and every label color should be different. For example Red area's label color should be white, light gray area's label color should be black. So I can specify the label text color according to the area color and here is the updated link with minimal code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/s9tu1c9y/136/)